# Splitting a string with regex - regex too greedy

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to split and extract all the strings with the format `linear-gradient(...)` within a string that may contain multiple occurrences e.g.
`linear-gradient(...), linear-gradient(...)`

My regex works fine for a single occurrence, but I can't get it to not be greedy after first occurrence. Any help would be appreciated.

A [regex101 version](https://regex101.com/r/oU4aC2/2)

The regex which works for a single occurrence

```
/.*gradient\s*\(((?:\([^\)]*\)|[^\)\(]*)*)\)/g
```

The string to be split

```
linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgb(0, 0, 0) 100%), linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(177, 186, 206) 0%, rgb(92, 158, 79) 50%, rgb(135, 218, 232) 100%)
```

the javascript

```js
var aGradient = [];
var gradientString = "linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgb(0, 0, 0) 100%), linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(177, 186, 206) 0%, rgb(92, 158, 79) 50%, rgb(135, 218, 232) 100%)";
var regex = /.*gradient\s*\(((?:\([^\)]*\)|[^\)\(]*)*)\)/g;
var match;
while (match = regex.exec(gradientString)) {
  aGradient.push(match[0]);
  console.log(match[0]);
}
```

Comment: Remove the `.*` at the beginning.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - I need to capture the whole "linear-gradient" string as part of the returned match. The string can also be `radial-gradient(...)`

Comment: Then replace `.*` with `(?:\w+-?)?`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/oU4aC2/3).

Comment: why not just change the regex to `/(?:\s*)linear-gradient\s*\(((?:\([^\)]*\)|[^\)\(]*)*)\)/g` ?  https://regex101.com/r/XxtPy6/1

Comment: You should make this an answer @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: @AndrewCherevatkin: OP did not confirm it is what is needed.

Comment: @jrook - your comment got me to the working solution: `(?:\s*)(?:linear|radial)-gradient\s*\(((?:\([^\)]*\)|[^\)\(]*)*)\)` - If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - Your answer works as well - thanks. I've made it more restrictive in my comment above.

Comment: You may remove `(?:\s*)` if you do not want the leading whitespace in the result.

Comment: @mseifert, I think  Wiktor Stribiżew gave the best possible solution. I deleted my answer and you should accept his :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.*` part at the beginning of the pattern matches *any 0+ chars other than line break chars as many as possible*. That means, you will only get the last match on a line.

It seems you just need to match any word that is present in front of the `-gradient`.  Replace `.*` with `\w+-`:

```
\w+-gradient\s*\(((?:\([^()]*\)|[^()]*)*)\)
^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oU4aC2/6). `\w+` matches 1 or more letters/digits/`_`.

If you know the values that can be there, use an alternation group:

```
(?:linear|radial)-gradient\s*\(((?:\([^()]*\)|[^()]*)*)\)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The `(?:linear|radial)` group will match either `linear` or `radial`.

*NOTE*: you do not need to escape `(` and `)` inside character classes.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - what is counter intuitive is that the `.* ` is at the beginning of the regex and yet it impacts it so that `you will only get the last match on a line` instead of picking up afresh where we left off after the first match was made. I don't yet grasp why this is the case.

Comment: It is easy. See, `.` matches any char but a line break char. `*` is a greedy quantifier, that makes the engine grab 0 or more of these chars immediately, so the whole line is matched with `.*`. Then backtracking occurs, and the engine substracts parts of the match to see if the obligatory patterns that follow `.*` can match. Once the full pattern matches, the match is returned, but the match that is at the end of the line will be there + something that was at the beginning.

Comment: Ah, finally makes sense. I've run up against this many times. Thanks again.